# How to create own responsive css grid system?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create own custom responsive css grid system like 960.gs, bootstrap etc. and I want to create my own system.

So, I'm just starting and trying to figure out.

I calculate it left and right padding 15px and my total width 960px.

***My calculation formula***

960px - 30px (left-right padding) = 930px

My grid 12 column

930/12 = 77,5px

Percentage calculation:

for my one colum
(77,5 / 930) X 100 = 8,33%

but my one column

```
.container .kol1    { width:5.208333333333333%;}
```

I calculte it with a online css grid generator. I think something incorrect my formula.

I tried to do with this method but I have met some problems. What is a better method of calculation? or What are your preferred methods?

The following is my sample css code:

```
    .container          { position:relative; padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; margin:0 auto; }
    .container          { width:960px; }


    .container .kol1, 
    .container .kol2,
    .container .kol3,
    .container .kol4,
    .container .kol5,
    .container .kol6,
    .container .kol7,
    .container .kol8,
    .container .kol9,
    .container .kol10,
    .container .kol11,
    .container .kol12   { margin-left:1.5625%; margin-right:1.5625%; float:left; display:inline; margin-bottom:30px; background-kolor:#f8f8f8; text-align:center; padding:30px 0;}

    .container .kol1    { width:5.208333333333333%;}
    .container .kol2    { width:13.54166666666667%;}
    .container .kol3    { width:21.875%;}
    .container .kol4    { width:30.20833333333333%;}
    .container .kol5    { width:38.54166666666667%;}
    .container .kol6    { width:46.875%;}
    .container .kol7    { width:55.20833333333333%;}
    .container .kol8    { width:63.54166666666666%;}
    .container .kol9    { width:71.875%;}
    .container .kol10   { width:80.20833333333333%;}
    .container .kol11   { width:88.54166666666666%;}
    .container .kol12   { width:96.875%;}
```

I think my math is bad :)

UPDATE:

Hi,

I think, It was a bad question. I will answer my question.

I have created a calculator for that grid system.

Enter Container size and margin, it will calculate it for you. If your column number more 12 then you must add a row on calculator :)

My calc link [here](http://instacalc.com/20021)

Comment: Why don't you want to use bootstrap or something famous and strong? Just to know.

Comment: I'm just trying to learn the system absolutely :) bootstrap is very good system..I want to know is how these calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculator subtract the margins from your 8,33%.

8,333333333333333% - 1.5625% - 1.5625% = 5.208333333333333%

Comment: Hey @BastianW yes it seems and thanks for answer. We individual can calculate it. I need a formula for their practical. Let's forget my example, how can can we calculate it? Our container width 960px and 12 grid. How would your formula for 12 grid and padding? Can you update your answer :)

Comment: are you familiar to lesscss? Then I would build some functions. But as Vadorequest said, it's all done yet by bootstrap and other frontend frameworks ^^

Comment: But if you want to do it without lesscss, then just put your calculations into your css. kol1 => 8,33333%, kol2 => kol1*2, ...and remove the margins. Not that hard ;)